# How can I set an interval to refresh location every 10 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geolocation

I have this code which is working fine and I want to "refresh" the location every 10 seconds, I searched and tried but I was not able to find the way

```
  var map, infoWindow;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 6
    });
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        }

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
        map.setCenter(pos);
```

I think that I should set an interval here but I don't know how.

```
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        interval
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
   'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
   'Error: Your browser doesn't support geolocation.');
    infoWindow.open(map);
  }
```

Comment: Any reason for updating every 10 secs? It will make you send more requests than needed = higher cost since GMaps charges for API requests. Wouldn't it make more sense updating if something has changed?

Comment: I want to make an app with html5 and sql using maps and i want to send current location in case i need to draw a mark in the map and see in real time other marks

Comment: If you're new then I get your approach, it's not very easy. But you should look up later on how to update on events instead of fixed times. It will increase performance and reduce cost. You just need to learn about how to keep and update the state for your app.

Comment: If you are watching the location changes why don't you use the `watchPosition()` function instead of the `getCurrentPosition()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API#Watching_the_current_position

Comment: And what do you recommend guys?

Answer (score 1):

I hope following solution will enlighten you a little bit, thanks.

```js
var map, infoWindow;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 6
  });
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  getCurrentPosition(map, infoWindow)


}

function getCurrentPosition(map, infoWindow) {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      }

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
      infoWindow.open(map);
      map.setCenter(pos);
      setTimeout(getCurrentPosition(map, infoWindow), 10000);

    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      interval
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }
}


function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
    'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
    "Error: Your browser doesn't support geolocation.");
  infoWindow.open(map);
}
```